# Shortcut to add multiple Tags (aka Labels) in Mac Finder

Tags: macos, finder, automator, shortcuts-app, finder-tag

Using either Shortcuts (or Automator if needed), I'm trying to add **multiple** tags (labels) to a file. It's simple to add a single tag, but that tag gets overwritten if you try adding another.

If you do this, you end up with only a blue tag; I would like blue and green together.

[image]

Comment: Do you really need them all in one keypress, or would one for each tag be OK? Ctrl/number will add tags to all files currently selected in Finder [but not if you use the same key commands for Spaces] https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchlp15236/mac

Comment: Wow, I'm a Mac veteran and never knew about the Ctrl/number shortcut. This is what I'll use for now. I'm still curious to see if it can be done as a single-keypress shortcut though.